# Selecting multiple items on an actionable list bootstrap, flask-wtf

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, flask-wtforms

I am trying to add a delete button to a searchable list of emails like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QRxLk.png)
I was wondering if anyone knows a way to highlight multiple items on a list like this and then send a list of the names to python when you hit the delete button? I can only find ways to do this with radios. I am sorry if this is a very basic question! I am just new to WTF forms and I cannot find anything on them relating to bootstrap lists.

Here is the code in question:

```
<div class="list-group-flush">
    <form class="form-inline" action="{{ url_for('home') }}" method ="POST">
    {% if data %}
    {% for x in data %}
        <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">{{ x }}</a>
    {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
    </form>
</div>
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using javascript (JS) you will struggle. JS allows you to react to a user's search entry and dynamically update the page using information that is fetched via a flask api route that will also search the db, and return info in JSON format.

If you insist on doing this without JS, then when you click `search` a Flask route will find the relevant emails and display them in a new `render_template`, everytime the user clicks search a new page is rendered which is often not optimal. I would then use a MultiCheckbox:

```
from wtforms import SelectMultipleField, widgets
class MultiCheckboxField(SelectMultipleField):
    widget = widgets.ListWidget(prefix_label=False)
    option_widget = widgets.CheckboxInput()

def Form(*search_options):
    class TempForm(FlaskForm):
        pass
    found_emails = some_db_query_method(*search_options)        
    setattr(TempForm, 'emails', MultiCheckboxField('List of queried emails',
                                 choices=[(x[0], x[1]) for x in found_emails])
    return TempForm()
```

You can configure the CSS to control the look and feel of your checkboxes, as part of the multicheckbox

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div class="list-group-flush">
  <form class="form-inline" action="{{ url_for('home') }}" method="POST">
    {% if data %}
    <select multiple id="mySelect">
      {% for x in data %}
      <option class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">{{ x }}</option>
      {% endfor %}
    </select>
    {% endif %}
  </form>
</div>
```

Try using a select form element with the ability to select multiple items. You can then access the values via form values.